# Passing value from activity to service android

Tags: android, audio, service, spinner

I am trying to pass a time value from my activity where the user selects it from a spinner, to the service so the audio clip will play for that length of time. So far I get no errors but the service does not play for the requested length of time. I did not post the logcat because I have no errors, I am assuming it is something simple I am overlooking. I want to take the TIME_IN_MINUTES value from the activity and have the service play for that long.

service class

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    long time = 0;
    if (intent.hasExtra("TIME_IN_MINUTESC")) {
        time = intent.getLongExtra("TIME_IN_MINUTES", 1000);
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Ship Service Started for" + time, 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    myPlayer.start();
}
}
```

activity class.

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.ship);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    stop1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    stop1.setOnClickListener(this);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TIME_IN_MINUTES);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
    Intent intService =  new Intent(Ship.this, Shipservice.class);
    intService.putExtra("TIME_IN_MINUTES", 1000);

}

// Handle button callback
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn2:
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting service");
        startService(new Intent(this, Shipservice.class));
        break;
    case R.id.stop:
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");
        stopService(new Intent(this, Shipservice.class));
        break;
    }
```

Comment: you can communicate with service by binding Activity to it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not started your `Service` start service like this..

```
Intent intService =  new Intent(Ship.this, Shipservice.class);
intService.putExtra("TIME_IN_MINUTES", 1000);
startService(intService);
```

And in button `onClick` you have started the Service but that Intent doesn't have put any values. Start the `Service` with same `Intnet` or add data to new `Intnet`.

Or Simply chage this method like this..

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn2:
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting service");
        startService(intService);
        break;
    case R.id.stop:
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");
        stopService(intService);
        break;
    }
```

take `intservice` as a private varialble..

Comment: Where exactly should I be placing the top part of your code? I placed it inside the oncreate() but it still does not see the StartService(intService); and outs a red line under the (intService)

Answer (score 0):

try this on activity class

```
intent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
    intent.putExtra("key", resultReceiver);

    startService(intent);
}

private final ResultReceiver resultReceiver = new ResultReceiver(
        new Handler()) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //do functionality
    };
};
```

In service class;-

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

           //do functionality


    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("key", "data to send");
    ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("key");
    receiver.send(0, bundle);

}
```